# Is it possible to run android studio in virtualbox?

Tags: android, android-studio, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04, xubuntu

My host is Windows 8.1 and guest is Xubuntu 14.04.02 and I'm trying to run Android studio emulator in Xubuntu. This is the error I'm getting:

```
/home/ravioli/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_21 -netspeed full -netdelay none
libGL error: pci id for fd 4: 80ee:beef, driver (null)
OpenGL Warning: glFlushVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerOutputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameteriNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glFinalCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glDeleteFencesNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glFinishFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGenFencesNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFenceivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glIsFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glSetFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glTestFenceNV not found in mesa table
libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
```

Is it possible to do this? 
3d is enabled in windows and checked on virtualbox machine settings.
Any help will be appreciated.

/********************************************************/

I did what Ankush suggested and now these are the errors I'm getting:

```
/home/ravioli/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_21_2 -netspeed full -netdelay none
libGL error: pci id for fd 4: 80ee:beef, driver (null)
OpenGL Warning: glFlushVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerOutputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameteriNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glFinalCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glDeleteFencesNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glFinishFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGenFencesNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFenceivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glIsFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glSetFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glTestFenceNV not found in mesa table
libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
```

I'd be happy for any help or suggestion.

Comment: Here is the original virtualbox issue for that: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12941

Comment: I have just bumped into the exact same issue, my Xubuntu 14.04 guest is running on a Windows 7 host though. Did you find a fix or workaround for this at all?

Comment: Sorry, but as far as I can tell, it's not solvable. I think the issue was with the drivers..

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Virtual-box Guest Additions installed? The Guest Additions give you *experimental* 3D acceleration support 
 [<kbd>See this link</kbd>](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-3d)

You could also try disabling 3D in virtual machine's settings, it may not be ideal but it should allow the emulator to run.

Comment: Forgot to mention, but the VB guest Additions is installed. At first the 3D was disabled and yet, the emulator does not run at all...

Comment: Try installing the 32-bit libraries with `sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1` then Install the OpenGL libraries with `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev`